# Create symlink with Web Application using IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, symlink

I want to create symlinks with a web application which is running in IIS 7.5. However during the creation the following error message appears:

```
A required privilege is not held by the client. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070522)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070522): A required privilege is not held by the client. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070522) at 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtrerrorInfo) at Uploader.SaveToDisk()
```

I have modified the "Local Policies / User Rights Assignment / Create symbolic links" to Everyone with secpol.msc but this modification didn't solve the problem.

Does anyone have encountered the same problem before or has any advice where to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the user used by IIS for Anonymous Authentication from IUSR to a user in the Administrators group.

To change this go to IIS / Authentication / Anonymous Authentication / Edit

I did this on my development machine. This is probably not the way to do it on a production server.

Comment: I have created a normal user with minimal permissions and the authorization to create symlinks which is now used by IIS. This works fine.